# ReactJS - Highlight the input fields only when it is changed

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and working on the form elements. I have a scenario where I need to highlight the input fields whenever I am making changes to the input fields. how do I keep the input fields( textbox, checkbox, and dropdown) highlighted only if edited and stays highlighted even after clicking on the other fields?

Here is the sample code that I am working on

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            isEditEnabled: ''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        ...
        ...
    }
    
    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        }); 
    }
    
    componentDidUpdate() {
    ....
    ....
       this.setState({
                
                isEditEnabled: this.props.isEditEnabled
                ....
        )}
    }
    
<div className="form-row">
    <div className="form-group col-md-3">
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input disabled={!this.state.isEditEnabled} name="firstName" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" id="firstName" />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group col-md-3">
        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input disabled={!this.state.isEditEnabled} name="lastName" value={this.state.LastName} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" id="lastName" />
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-3">
       <select className="form-control" name="gender" onChange={this.handleChange}>
        ........
       </select> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Can this be done using the CSS selector? Can someone tell me how to implement it here?

Thanks

Comment: from the top of my mind you can create more state = { filedsEdited: { firstName: false, ...} ...} then on edit set it to true and set highlight class to input based on this

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you share me an example to achieve as I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example solution, based on your request, that after edited the inputs will remain highlighted even when clicking on another place or input:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      isEditEnabled: this.props.isEditEnabled,
      highlightedFieldNames: [],
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    // ...
    // ...
  }

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
      highlightedFieldNames: this.state.highlightedFieldNames.includes(name)
        ? this.state.highlightedFieldNames
        : [...this.state.highlightedFieldNames, name],
    }); 
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    // ....
    // ....
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-row">
        <div className="form-group col-md-3">
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <input disabled={this.state.isEditEnabled} name="firstName" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleInputChange} type="text" id="firstName" className={this.state.highlightedFieldNames.includes('firstName') ? 'highlighted-input' : ''} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-md-3">
          <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <input disabled={this.state.isEditEnabled} name="lastName" value={this.state.LastName} onChange={this.handleInputChange} type="text" id="lastName" className={this.state.highlightedFieldNames.includes('lastName') ? 'highlighted-input' : ''} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-3">
         <select className="form-control" name="gender" onChange={this.handleInputChange} className={this.state.highlightedFieldNames.includes('gender') ? 'highlighted-input' : ''}>
           ........
         </select> 
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```

Added `highlightedFieldNames` array to the state, and that's where you keep track of all the inputs that have already been edited.
Also changed the onChange function of inputs to `handleInputChange`, assuming that's what you were aiming for with `handleChange`.

The css could be implemented like this:

```
input {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
 
input.highlighted-input {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
```

What you should be expecting by copy pasting this piece of code in your project (css and the component are two different files)

[image: preview of rendered code]

Comment: When I try to implement the solution, it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: highlightedFieldNames is not defined at handleInputChange"

Comment: Also, I am unable to type any in the inputbox

Comment: @Geek Hi, I fixed the issue, I had forgotten to reference `highlightedFieldNames` as `this.state.highlightedFieldNames`. That was my mistake, but please keep in mind that when getting code from stackoverflow, you shouldn't just copy paste the solution, but look into it, try to understand it and ask questions where you aren't clear about what it does.

Comment: @Geek Edited some more, now it should render properly. The issues I fixed were, transforming `handleChange` into an arrow function, so `this.setState` calls work as without conflicting with the context of the handleChange function; removed `this.setState` call from `componentDidUpdate`, since it causes infinite rendering (added initialisation of `isEditEnabled` directly on `constructor`); removed `!` from the disabled prop on inputs, that was wrong, if you are expecting them to not be disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am still learning and new to react that's the reason I was unable to figute it.